# PHP to display list of WordPress Posts by Author of the current page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm not a pro coder but sometimes I do ok ;)  That being said, I'm trying to create some php code to get the current author and then display a list of WordPress posts from category x.

this code works but is static:

```
<?php query_posts('cat=665&author=37&order=ASC&showposts=-1'); ?> 
<?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?> code here
```

This code works great. It displays 3 posts.

So I created this code to make the author based on the author of the page.  It works but only displays one post. It stops after 1... :( Any idea why?

```
<?php 
$author_ID = get_query_var('author');
$t = 'cat=666&author=' . $author_ID . '&order=ASC&showposts=1';
query_posts($t);
if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
$t = 'cat=666&author=' . $author_ID . '&order=ASC&showposts=1';
```

to

```
$t = 'cat=666&author=' . $author_ID . '&order=ASC&showposts=-1';
```

Comment: one more question for you - if i may.  How can I change this to display up to 10 posts only?  THANK YOU!